# Why is this Python program running slower than i expected?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, path

I have two test programs both take a picture, but one writes it as temporary **RGB** data using numpy's `zeros()` function. While the other writes to **Disk** using cv2's `.imwrite()` module. So, my problem is that for my use the RGB version is obviously the better way to go, so I can avoid manipulating paths and disk memory, **but** my quarrel is that both programs run almost at the same speed as each other. I was made to believe that the program should run way faster when assigning an array to a variable **VS.** writing to drive and manipulating its file path. Am I doing some wrong or some weird unorthodox thing that just so happens to be really slow? The faster this program can take the picture the better for my purpose. Thanks again for any advice!

**RGB Version**

```
start = timeit.default_timer()
import numpy as np 
import cv2
def Array_Test():

    hud_Cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) 

    #If Hud camera is not found
    if not hud_Cam.isOpened():
        #Log error to console
        raise RuntimeError('Error opening Hud Camera.')
        
    #Set resolution of camera to 720p
    hud_Cam.set(3, 1280)
    hud_Cam.set(4, 720)
    
    while True:
        #Read/Grab Hud camera frame
        rval, hud_Img = hud_Cam.read()
        hud_Cam.release()
        snapshot = np.zeros(hud_Img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        snapshot = hud_Img.copy()
        print(snapshot)
        break
Array_Test()
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Program Timer: ', stop - start)
```

**Disk Version**

```
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
import cv2
import os

#Call Hud camera resource
hud_Cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) 
#If Hud camera is not found
if not hud_Cam.isOpened():
    #Log error to console
    raise RuntimeError('Error opening Hud Camera.')
    hud_Cam.release()
def _HudCam_(hud_Cam): #Define Hud Camera Function

    #Set resolution of camera to 720p
    hud_Cam.set(3, 1280)
    hud_Cam.set(4, 720)

    #Read/Grab Hud camera frame
    rval, hud_Img = hud_Cam.read()
        
    #Initialize file name
    hud_name = ('C:/Users/Logan/Downloads/HudPicture-0.jpg') 

    #Write Hud camera frame to file name
    cv2.imwrite(hud_name, hud_Img) 

    #Initialize rename hud jpg variable
    old_file1 = os.path.join("C:/Users/Logan/Downloads", "HudPicture-0.jpg") 

    #Initialize rename hud jpg variable
    new_file1 = os.path.join("C:/Users/Logan/Downloads", "HudPicture0.jpg") 

    #If a file exists under the renamed files path
    if (os.path.exists('C:/Users/Logan/Downloads/HudPicture0.jpg')):
        #Delete the file in the path
        os.remove('C:/Users/Logan/Downloads/HudPicture0.jpg')

    #Rename file so labview knows its not being written to
    os.rename(old_file1, new_file1) 

    #Log to console
    print("Hud Picture written!") 

    #Release camera resource to clear memory
    hud_Cam.release() 
_HudCam_(hud_Cam)
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print(stop - start)
```

Comment: Use a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to find the bottlenecks in each version. Also why do you have a while loop if at the end of this while loop you have a `break` statement ?

Comment: idk lol but I mean it doesn't anything I don't think does it? what is a profiler

Comment: There is a link in my comment.

Comment: I got rid of the while loop. I can't remember why I had it. I think i was using it to loop cv2.imshow() to keep the window open during testing

Comment: 214 function calls (207 primitive calls) in 0.000 seconds

Comment: Thats what was printed

Comment: IMHO the problem is bad measurement. Single sample, which includes things like importing Numpy and OpenCV, contructing a VideoCapture instance, etc. won't tell you much about the short little algorithm performed once after all of that.

Comment: I fixed my profiler i don't think i did it right the first time.  1328 function calls (1168 primitive calls) in 2.889 seconds

Comment: Please explain what you mean by bad measurement

Comment: nvm i figured it out I found a decent cprofiler and was able to cut it down to about 1.08 - 1.11